# Real time output whilst running Python

Tags: python, chatroom

I'm making a basic chatroom and I want the received messages to show up when I'm also typing a message. I've looked it up, but from what I can tell it only works with a GUI, and I would prefer not to write a GUI.

```
import socket
import time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
str_return = ("")
str_send = ("blep")
old = ("blep")
port = input("Enter Port ")
try:
    s.connect(("localhost", int(port)))
    print("Connecting")
    while True:
        str_send = input("Enter message: ")
        if str_send == ("exit"):
            break
        s.send(bytes(str_send, 'utf-8'))
        str_recv = s.recv(1024)
        print(str_recv.decode('utf-8'))
s.close()
except:
    print("setting up server")
    s.bind(('localhost', int(port)))
    s.listen(5)
    connect, addr = s.accept()
    connect.sendto(bytes(str_return, 'utf-8'), addr)
    print("Connection Address:" + str(addr))
    while True:
        str_send = input("Enter message: ")
        if str_send == ("exit"):
            break
        connect.sendto(bytes(str_send, 'utf-8'), addr)
        str_recv, temp = connect.recvfrom(1024)
        print(str_recv.decode('utf-8'))


print("bye")
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: There are a number of ways you could add a "typing" notification from text elsewhere on the screen, to an audible beep. Which are you trying to achieve? You haven't asked a question here, merely stated a problem.

Comment: you can use multithreading for that

Comment: Side Note: Your `s.close()` is badly indented, unless it's a problem with pasting of the code this will cause you trouble later

Comment: As per your problem - you have 2 possibilities here: Remove blocking calls (such as `input`) replacing them with an async mechanism, like `select` or `poll`. Or parallelize your program using threads (processes will not be suitable for this kind of software).